# How to push with not in condition mongoose?

Tags: mongoose, aggregation-framework

I have this Document schema tree:

```json
{
    "id": "1",
    "name": "new collection",
    "desc": "",
    "sections": [
        {
            "id": "1",
            "name": "new section",
            "order": 0,
            "documents": [
                {
                    "id": "1",
                    "name": "document 1",
                    "members": [
                        {
                            "id": ObjectId("1")
                        }
                    ]
                }
            ]
        }
    ]
}
```

How can I push a member to a document by that document's id with the condition that the member to add is not in existed members document?

I followed other questions and try this but not work:

```js
db.collection.findOneAndUpdate({
  'sections.documents._id': docId
}, {
  $push: {
    $cond: [
      {
        $not: [{
          $anyElementTrue: {
            $map: {
              input: 'sections.$.documents.$[i].members',
              as: 'el',
              in: { $eq: ['$$el', member] }
            }
          }
        }]
      },
      { 'sections.$.documents.$[i].members': member },
      null
    ]
  }
}, {
  new: true,
  arrayFilters: [{
    'i._id': docId
  }]
});
```

Thank you for reading.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I used $addToSet and everything works fine!
https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/operator/update/addToSet/

```js
db.collection.findOneAndUpdate({
  'sections.documents._id': docId
}, {
  $addToSet: { 'sections.$.documents.$[i].members': member }
}, {
  new: true,
  arrayFilters: [{
    'i._id': docId
  }]
});
```